# Is there a way to archive Live Photos to the filesystem on macOS?

Tags: macos, iphone, photos.app

I like the ability to take Live Photos on my iPhone.

I bought a Mac and I can see them in the Photos App, but when I transfer them to my personal folders in my account, the live effect is lost.

Is there any way to transfer them to folders without losing that Live feature?

Comment: I’ve edited this to indicate you’re archiving or duplicating them outside the library. Hopefully someone can guess how you transfer them (or it doesn’t matter if you choose export or drag them) and it doesn’t matter what version of photos and macOS. I’ll try this once I get back to my mac later in the weekend to see if there’s a quick answer how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What I have found is the ability to export the .JPG and .MOV versions of the same photo to a folder in Mac.

Go to File-> Export-> Export unmodified original. Then chose the folder. This created a .JPG and a .MOV file with the same first name. I imported both of them together using cmd+shift+I and they appeared as one.

I checked (but not thoroughly) through Pictures-> Photos Library.photoslibrary right click-> show package contents. Couldn't find mov files. I recommend someone to check it.